# Where do I specify Base Url in Nexus Repository Manager 3.0 (Milestone 7 Release)?

Tags: nexus

In Nexus 2.11.4-01 I am able to specify Base Url in Application Server Settings.
Where do I specify Base Url in Nexus Repository Manager 3.0 (Milestone 7 Release)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to "administration/capabilities", then click on "create capability", and you'll see it there.

Note that this functionality was hidden under capabilities because it isn't needed in almost all cases.